# Is there any closed form for the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln ^{n} x}{1+x^{2}} d x$, where $n\in \mathbb N?$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

***Latest Edit***

Thanks to @Claude Leibovici and @Gary for giving us the closed form of the integral.

Using [MA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nth%20derivative%20of%20sec%20x), we have

$$\frac{d^{ n}}{d{x}^{n}}\left(\sec x\right)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2 k-n) !} E_{2 k} x^{2 k-n} $$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln ^{2 n} x}{1+x^{2}} d x=&\left.\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\partial^{2 n}}{\partial{a}^{2 n}}\left(\sec \left(\frac{a \pi}{2}\right)\right)\right|_{a=0} \\
=&\left.\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2 n+1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2 k-2 n) !} E_{2 k} \left(\frac{a\pi}{2} \right) ^{2 k-2 n}\right|_{a=0} \\
=&\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2 n+1}(-1)^{n} E_{2 n} \\
=&\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2 n+1}\left|E_{2 n}\right|
\end{aligned}
$$
where $E_{2 k}$ is an [Euler number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerNumber.html).

For example, $$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln ^{20} x}{1+x^{2}} d x &=\frac{\pi^{21}}{2^{21}}|E _{10}| =\frac{370371188237525 \pi^{21}}{2097152},
\end{aligned}
$$
checked by [MA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20%20%E2%88%AB_0%5E%E2%88%9Eln%5E%2820%29x%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29dx%20).

---

Noting that $$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^{2n-1}x}{1+x^2} d x &=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{1+\frac{1}{x^{2}}} \cdot \frac{d x}{x^{2}} =-\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln ^{2 n-1} x}{x^{2}+1} d x,
\end{aligned}
$$
we have $$
I_{2n-1}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln ^{2 n-1} x}{1+x^{2}} d x=0
$$

How about
$$I_{2n}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln ^{2 n} x}{1+x^{2}} d x?$$

I like to switch the integration problem to a differentiation problem by defining a new integral.
$$
J(a):=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{a}}{1+x^{2}} d x
$$

Then $$
I_{k}=J^{(k)}(0)
$$
By my [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4397733/732917)

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{r}}{x^{m}+1} d x=\frac{\pi}{m} \csc \frac{(r+1) \pi}{m},$$
we have
$$
J(a)=\frac{\pi}{2} \csc \frac{(a+1) \pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2} \sec \left(\frac{a \pi}{2}\right)
$$

Then $$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln ^{2n} x}{1+x^{2}} d x &=\left.\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^{2}} \frac{\partial^{2n}}{\partial a^{2n}}\left(x^{a}\right) d x\right|_{a=0} \\
&=\boxed{\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{d^{2n}}{d a^{2n}}\left[\left.\sec \left(\frac{a \pi}{2}\right) \right]\right|_{a=0}}
\end{aligned}
$$

For examples, $$
\begin{aligned}
I_{2}&=\left.\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{d^{2}}{d a^{2}} \sec \left(\frac{a \pi}{2}\right)\right|_{a=0}=\frac{\pi^{3}}{8} \\
I_{4}&=\left.\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{d^{4}}{d a^{4}} \sec \left(\frac{a \pi}{2}\right)\right|_{a=0}=\frac{5 \pi^{5}}{32}\\ &\qquad \vdots
\end{aligned}
$$

---

***Alternative method***(By reduction formula)

Applying Leibniz’s Rule and differentiating the following equation w.r.t $a$ by $n$ times$$
J(a) \cos \frac{a \pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2} ,
$$
we have $$
\sum_{k=0}^{2 n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 n \\
k
\end{array}\right) \left[\cos \left(\frac{a \pi}{2}\right)\right]^{(2 n-k)}  J^{(k)}(a)=0
$$

Putting $a=0$ yields $$
\sum_{k=0}^{2 n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 n \\
k
\end{array}\right) \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2 n-k}\cos \left(\frac{(2 n-k) \pi}{2}\right)I_{k}=0
$$

Since $I_{2k-1}=0,$ we have found a reduction formula relating $I_{2k}$.$$
\boxed{\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{l}
2 n \\
2 k
\end{array}\right)\left(\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}\right)^{n-k} \cos (n-k) \pi I_{2 k}=0}
$$

For example, $$
\begin{aligned}
\left(\begin{array}{l}
4 \\
0
\end{array}\right)\left(\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}\right)^{2} I_{0}+\left(\begin{array}{l}
4 \\
2
\end{array}\right)\left(\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}\right)  I_{2}+\left(\begin{array}{l}
4 \\
4
\end{array}\right) I_{4}=0 . \\
\frac{\pi^{4}}{16} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}-6 \cdot \frac{\pi^{2}}{4}\left(\frac{\pi^{3}}{8}\right)+I_{4}=0 \\
I_{4}=-\frac{\pi^{5}}{32}+\frac{6 \pi^{5}}{3 \cdot 2}=\frac{5 \pi^{5}}{32}
\end{aligned}
$$

checked by [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20%20%E2%88%AB_0%5E%E2%88%9Eln%5E%282%2A2%29x%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29dx%20).

***My Question***
Is there any formula for the $n^{th}$ derivative of $\sec x$?

Your opinions and alternative solutions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Mathematica says:$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\ln ^n(x)}{1+x^2} \, dx=4^{-1-n} \left(1+(-1)^n\right) \Gamma (1+n) \left(\zeta \left(1+n,\frac{1}{4}\right)-\zeta
   \left(1+n,\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Is there any formula for the $n^{th}$ derivative of $\sec x$?  See https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sec/20/02/  Maple gave me the second one of these (with the Stirling numbers of the second kind).

Comment: $$\frac{\partial ^n\sec (x)}{\partial x^n}=2^n e^{-\frac{1}{2} i (n \pi +2 x)} \left(\Phi \left(-e^{-2 i x},-n,\frac{1}{2}\right)+e^{i (n \pi +2 x)} \Phi \left(-e^{2 i x},-n,\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$ where $\Phi$ is  Lerch transcendent function.

Comment: Or: $\frac{\partial ^n\sec (x)}{\partial x^n}=(2 \pi )^{-1-n} \Gamma (1+n) \left(\zeta \left(1+n,\frac{\pi -2 x}{4 \pi }\right)-\zeta \left(1+n,\frac{3}{4}-\frac{x}{2 \pi
   }\right)+(-1)^n \left(\zeta \left(1+n,\frac{\pi +2 x}{4 \pi }\right)-\zeta \left(1+n,\frac{3}{4}+\frac{x}{2 \pi }\right)\right)\right)$ if $2 x<\pi$

Comment: Thank you for so many formula for the derivative, I shall try later.

Comment: How did you get $$\left.\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2 n+1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2 k-2 n) !} E_{2 k} \left(\frac{a\pi}{2} \right) ^{2 k-2 n}\right|_{a=0} 
=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2 n+1}(-1)^{n} E_{2 n} $$

Comment: When $k\not = n, \left.\left(\frac{a\pi}{2}\right)^{2k-2n}\right|_{a=0 }=0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$I_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log ^{2n} (x)}{1+x^{2}}\, d x=\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^{2 n+1} \,\left|E_{2 n}\right|$$

Comment: It seems to me that $E_{2n}$ are the [Euler numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerNumber.html). Those are rather different from the zigzag numbers. The zigzag numbers have two parameters.

Comment: @Gary. You are right (once more !)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, thank you for your wonderful answer.  Please let me elaborate it as the latest edit.

Comment: @Gary, thank you for your reference about Euler numbers which help me understand what $E_{2n}$ is.